# CSS "position:fixed" rendering in FF 3.5 vs. 3.0

Tags: html, css, firefox

Is there a fundamental difference between how `position:fixed;` is handled by Firefox 3.0 and Firefox 3.5?

I ask this because I had been using Firefox 3 as the development platform for an ongoing project and this was upgraded to Firefox 3.5 today.

The structure creating the trouble is a div situated at the very top of the viewport `position:fixed; top:0; z-index:3`

This div sits on top of a large image which may be scrolled down by the user.

Previously, with FF 3.0, the image used to scroll smoothly without affecting the top div. However, with FF 3.5, the **top div flickers and oscillates** about its supposed position as the image scrolls!

Does anybody know how to get the top div back to serenity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166816/firefox-3-5-fixed-position-scrolling-annoying-flicker) you can add overflow:auto to the element.

Comment: This issue is being tracked in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=531461 and should be fixed by Firefox 3.6 final.